# What is the most efficient password scheme in terms of entropy per convenience

Tags: passwords, entropy

[image]
Although the main points are right, but now [six words are needed](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2014/03/diceware-passwords-now-need-six-random-words-to-thwart-hackers/), which is both inconvenient to remember, and inconvenient to type.

My question is, has then been any case studies on the **most convenient** schemes for entropy produced, where convenience is a tradeoff between memorablity and easiness to type.

- Random Characters are easy to type but hard to remember
- Random Words are easy to remember but hard to type

Comment: This is impossible to answer objectively. Every person will have a different idea of what is convenient enough or secure enough and every situation is different such as a bank compared a college student's senior project will require a different ratio of security to convenience. I would argue it's better to be more secure than convenient then tune it down over time to fit your user's needs.

Comment: @GingerBeard That's why I am asking for a scheme. Both a banker and college student want the most bits for their inconvenience, whether its because they want more bits or less inconvience.

Comment: I assume you mean in English? Different languages and cultures will have different results of any "study".

Comment: While I can't be certain, I assume the original poster meant a study along the lines of: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case_study

Comment: I answered [a similar question](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/85762/8340) yesterday. I'm not aware of any studies as increasing how easy to type is a very subjective measure and also reduces entropy.

Comment: possible duplicate of [XKCD #936: Short complex password, or long dictionary passphrase?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6095/xkcd-936-short-complex-password-or-long-dictionary-passphrase)